# В каком порядке будут выполняться задания cron

Tags: cron

Допустим, есть такой *crontab* с гипотетическими заданиями:

```
*/5 * * * *  job1 &
*/10 * * * * job2
*/15 * * * * job3
```

Все задачи выполняются примерно минуту. Как они будут выполняться, скажем, в 03:30?

1. job1 уходит в background и там начинает свою работу, потом запускается и отрабатывает job2, после этого запускается и отрабатывает job3.
2. Последовательно запускаются все три задания, и все три работают одновременно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ровно в 3:30 запустятся одновременно три задачи.
Ну может не совсем одновременно, а с задержкой в несколько тактов, но это уже не суть важно.

Comment: Действительно. Завёл тестовый будильник. Все три задачи отработали секунда в секунду. Разницы от добавления `&` не было.